# how to implement voip in android

Tags: android, call, voip

I want to use voip functionality in android. 
What can I use to implement voip functionality in android?.

It is required that same application is install on receive side mobile. Please post links or source so that I can implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [sipDroid](http://android.appstorm.net/reviews/communication/sipdroid-a-robust-open-source-voip-client/) . Its open source client for Voip calls. Follow the link i shared you will get all the details you need.

There is one more demo app from google called [SipDemo](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/2.3/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html). Its bundled with android itself

Comment: The first link is redirecting to a different page than intended.